# Dual Monitor/Xinerama not working; cannot even detect on-board graphic card

Tags: multiple-monitors, kubuntu

I have Kubuntu 12.04 and two identical VGA monitors. One I plugged via DVI-VGA adapter into the DVI port of my discrete AMD Radeon HD 6670, the other into the VGA port of my on-board graphic card (Radeon HD 6410D).

After installing Kubuntu I got a black screen, so I booted with `nomodeset` and installed AMD's catalyst drivers but only the monitor plugged into the discrete graphic card worked.

Using `lspci` I saw that the on-board graphics was not listed. Then I found in the BIOS settings the options "Surround View" and "Onboard Dual Link DVI" both disabled. After enabling both, the on-board graphics card shows up in `lspci` but in `amdcccle`, it only shows as `[Uknown display]Uknown adapter`.

When I try to enable xinerama, I get a black screen after rebooting on both monitors. I tried several options and hints from the web but nothing worked so far. I also reinstalled the AMD drivers several times.

What should I do?

Edit: Do you think it would help if I buy another DVI-VGA adapter and try to plug the monitor via this adapter into the DVI port of the on-board graphics card?

---

Okay, I think I try the additional DVI-VGA adapter and report back when this also does not work.